# How to add the new material components widgets in the Android Studio designer?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, material-components-android

[image]

How to add the new Material Components widgets from the designer (not XML)?

Like MaterialButton, MaterialTextView etc.

Comment: I guess you can't modify the palette components

Comment: @AbhishekDutt No. Adding MC dependency does not have any effect on the designer.

Comment: if you are using a material theme , all these components will be material components.